# Firebase App crash when I open it initialize

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, aide-ide

When I add this

```
        demoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("txt");
```

My App crash and when I delete it the app work can someone help me .

I tried many ways like change the version of database but nothing work and it take me more than 3 weeks without any solve

**This is my Mainactivity**

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

```
private HashMap <String,Object>map=new HashMap();
private Button send;
private EditText edit;
private DatabaseReference demoRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    demoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("txt");

    send=findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
    edit=findViewById(R.id.mainEditText1);


}
```

}

**This is my build**

```
dependencies {
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:+'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is my Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.firebase, PID: 5291
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firebase/com.firebase.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.firebase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6677)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
... 9 more
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.firebase, PID: 8039
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firebase/com.firebase.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.firebase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6677)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

and just let the reference like this

```
private HashMap <String,Object>map=new HashMap();
private Button send;
private EditText edit;
private DatabaseReference demoRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    demoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("txt");

    send=findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
    edit=findViewById(R.id.mainEditText1);


}
```

And make sure you have the INTERNET permission in your manifest

Comment: can you share your crashlog ?

Comment: It's show the same thing and ask from me to make initialize firebase

Answer (score 0):

remove `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` from `MainActivity` and put it in onCreate of your app's `Application` class. [Look here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application).

By the way, What is the API LEVEL you're testing? From **Marshmallow** onwards
you'll need to add **runtime permissions** to your app. and you probably need **`WRITE_STORAGE` permission** to use the local database.

Hope this helps!